# Drupal views slideshow cycle: pause/resume not working

Tags: drupal-7, view, slideshow, cycle

I have a dp7 site where I have added a sliding banner using views slideshow cycle.

One of my slides have a youtube video and I am trying to pause the slideshow when the video is playing and resume sliding when the video stops.

I have added the YT callback functions successfully and I am detecting the play/stop video status changes. But, when I call the cycle('pause') and cycle('resume') on my slideshow, It does not work. On the other hand, the cycle('stop') works fine, but I am unable to restart the slideshow again.

Any idea how to achieve this in a correct drupal way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you found this page through search like I did, here's a drupal Views Slideshow method for pause/play (works with Cycle, not sure with others):

Pause:

```
Drupal.viewsSlideshow.action({ "action": 'pause', "slideshowID": "YOURSLIDESHOWID", "force": true });
```

Play:

```
Drupal.viewsSlideshow.action({ "action": 'play', "slideshowID": "YOURSLIDESHOWID", "force": true });
```

You can see your YOURSLIDESHOWID in the page source, everything that goes after views_slideshow_cycle_main_ is your ID:

```
<div id="views_slideshow_cycle_main_slideshow-block" class="views_slideshow_cycle_main views_slideshow_main viewsSlideshowCycle-processed"
```

In my case slideshow id was "slideshow-block".

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the origin of this issue:

When the option 'pause' is set to 1 (pause on hover), when you pause the slideshow by calling cycle('pause'), then move the mouse over the slide, it reactivates the slideshow and resumes it.
So in order for cycle('pause') to keep the slideshow paused, you need to disable the pause on hover by setting 'pause' to 0.

Honestly, I find this illogical and hope it has been changed in cycle2. If I chose to pause a slideshow, whether I hover over the slides or not, it should not change my slideshow status. Nothing should cancel the cycle('pause') event but the cycle('resume').

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering which selector to use, as I was for a while, it's the one right before the div's that you were using.

In Drupal 8, with the machine name `slideshow` and the display `block_1`, mine was:

`#views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_fp_slideshow-block_1`